# Masonary image not positioning correctly on ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, masonry

I am using https://masonry.desandro.com/ v4.2.2 and the minimal code looks like:

```
<div class="fk-grid-container" id="ajax-concepts">
<?php
//This is just the wordpress loop and currently its looping and showing 3 items
//LOOP START
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    $thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('','full');
?>
    <div class="fk-grid-item">
        <a href="<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>" class="gallery-link">
            <div
                    class="boxes"
                    data-aos="fade-down"
                    data-aos-duration="2000"
            >
                <div class="images-box">
                    <img
                            src="<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>"
                            class="img-fluid"
                            alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php
//LOOP END
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

And, I have initalized it as :

```
jQuery(".fk-grid-container").imagesLoaded(function () {
    jQuery(".fk-grid-container").masonry({
        itemSelector: ".fk-grid-item",
        gutter: 30,
    });
    AOS.refresh();
});
```

Upto this point its fine, now on click load more, I am making an ajax call and on success it is returning html as:

```
<div class="fk-grid-item">
   <a href="http://famous.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/02.png" class="gallery-link">
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
         <div class="images-box"><img src="http://famous.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/02.png"  class="img-fluid"  alt="Image 3" /></div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="fk-grid-item">
   <a href="http://famous.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/05.png" class="gallery-link">
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
         <div class="images-box"><img src="http://famous.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/05.png"  class="img-fluid"  alt="Image 2" /></div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="fk-grid-item">
   <a href="http://famous.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/06.png" class="gallery-link">
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
         <div class="images-box"><img src="http://famous.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/06.png"  class="img-fluid"  alt="Image 1" /></div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

and my ajax success:

```
success: function(data){
    var $data = jQuery(data);
    if($data.length){
        jQuery(".fk-grid-container").append(data).masonry( 'reloadItems' );
        AOS.refresh();
    }
},
```

But, with this code the image are not aligned to correct position and is displayed as:

[image: Wrong stacking image]

This is what it looked initially:

[image: Initially]

What it should look like:

[image]

**Update**:

I have tried with:

```
var $grid = $('.fk-grid-container');
$grid.masonry()
    .append( $data )
    .masonry( 'appended', $data )
    .layout();
AOS.refresh();
```

I have tried with above code, it is adding the new content but it is not increasing the height of current container and instead overlapping over next container. With this the load data button is covered by the data so I can't make another request.

Comment: Again init like `$grid.masonry('layout');` You can check method from this link https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html  or append more items like this method `$grid.masonry( 'appended', elements )` so check link and find which method you want.

Comment: I have updated the code to: `var $grid = $('.fk-grid-container');
$grid.masonry()
    .append( $data )
    .masonry( 'appended', $data )
    .layout();
AOS.refresh();`

But it is not pushing the container, that means, layout seems correct to some extend but it is overlapping to next container instead of increasing the height of current container.

Answer (score 1):

On load more, it looks like you are not making use of `imagesLoaded` correctly.

Let's take a look at your initialization code:

```
jQuery(".fk-grid-container").imagesLoaded(function () {
    jQuery(".fk-grid-container").masonry({
        itemSelector: ".fk-grid-item",
        gutter: 30,
    });
    AOS.refresh();
});
```

above one is correct

But, on success (according to your last update) you are doing as:

```
var $grid = $('.fk-grid-container');
$grid.masonry()
    .append( $data )
    .masonry( 'appended', $data )
    .layout();
AOS.refresh();
```

Actually, the above code is somehow correct you just need to update the layout once all the images are loaded and you have to update that `layout` part to `masonry` (because it looks like you are using jquery). Just like here, mentioned in the first block https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html

So, the final code should look like this:

```
var $grid = $('.fk-grid-container');
//appending the data on the grid 
$grid.masonry()
    .append( $data )
    .masonry( 'appended', $data );


$grid.imagesLoaded(function(){
//once images are fully loaded, you update the layout
    $grid.masonry();
    AOS.refresh();
});
```

Hope, it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `appended` & `reloadItems` method after click to to Load More button and then call `imageLoaded` method to check all images are loaded or not then again need to call `layout` method in masonry for adjusting(update) items.

**Helpful links for** *masonry methods*:
https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout-masonry
https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended
https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#reloaditems

I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

```js
var $grid = $('#ajax-concepts') //grid container

$grid.imagesLoaded().done(function (instance) {
    $grid.masonry({
        itemSelector: ".fk-grid-item",
        gutter: 30,
    });
    // Initialize AOS plugin
    AOS.init();
});

// $data like ajax success items
var $data = `<div class="fk-grid-item">
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">
            <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
                <div class="images-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x650/099900/" class="img-fluid" alt="Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="fk-grid-item">
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">
            <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
                <div class="images-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/999000/" class="img-fluid" alt="Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="fk-grid-item">
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">
            <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
                <div class="images-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x220/000000/" class="img-fluid" alt="Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>`;

$(document).on('click', '#loadmore', function() { 
    $grid.masonry().append($data).masonry('appended', $data).masonry('reloadItems');
    $grid.imagesLoaded(function () {
        //once images are fully loaded, you update the layout
        $grid.masonry('layout');
        // Initialize AOS plugin after append new items
        AOS.init();
        //Page scroll down at load more button 
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#loadmore").offset().top
        },1500);
    });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.fk-grid-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.fk-grid-container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.fk-grid-item{
    max-width: calc(33.333333% - 30px);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.img-fluid{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .fk-grid-item{
        max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>

<div class="fk-grid-container" id="ajax-concepts">
    <div class="fk-grid-item">
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">
            <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
                <div class="images-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x500/0000FF/" class="img-fluid" alt="Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="fk-grid-item">
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">
            <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
                <div class="images-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/FF00FF/" class="img-fluid" alt="Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="fk-grid-item">
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">
            <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
                <div class="images-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x600/00FFFF/" class="img-fluid" alt="Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="fk-grid-item">
        <a href="#" class="gallery-link">
            <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-duration="2000">
                <div class="images-box">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x450/09F900/" class="img-fluid" alt="Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center; padding: 20px; clear: both;">
    <button type="button" style="padding: 10px 40px;" id="loadmore">Load More</button>
</div>
```